Identify meat slicer
I need help identifying this meat slicer.  It has no decals or markings on it anywhere and I would like to buy it a new sharpener.
I’m hoping someone might recognize it! Thank you. 

If you could edit into the question where you are in the world (I guess country would be enough) that might help narrow it down. Decals might be on the underside.

Hello.   It’s in the USA.  I searched all over and there’s no markings, not even on the motor.  There was some sticky residue on the lower right as you look at it, which must be where there was a label but it’s gone.

It was worth a shot. If you don't have any luck here, one way might be to take it to a local auction house and see if they can ID; they've often seen lots of these sorts of things over time. Based on the cream-coloured knobs, I'd guess some time prior to 2000 as I see similar knobs on that era equipment in my scientific labs.

Ok thank you Bob, appreciate it.

Restaurant supply stores might be able to ID this as well. They may even carry replacement/compatible parts, etc. - It does seem rather odd that there are no marking at all - even on the electrical bits like the motor. Those bits usually have at least specification markings on them.
